# Возможно ли создать линукс с разделением системных папок и папок приложений и с дополнительным аккаунтом администратора?

Tags: linux

Меня интересует вопрос: завязано ли ядро линукс на системных папках типа `/dev`, `/etc`, `/proc` и т.д.?

Возможно ли на ядре линукс сделать систему, корневая папка которой будет выглядеть следующим образом (примерно): ?

```
Applications
Devices
Libraries
System
Users
```

Ещё, мне кажется, было бы удобно сделать аккаунт администратора (`admin` - не `root`), который имел бы доступ к папкам `Applications` и `Libraries`, но не имел доступ к папке `System` (в отличие от `root`). Можно ли такое сделать?

Comment: Даже если эти  имена используются в коде, то они наверняка определены в каких-то .h файлах. Заменяйте, пересобирайте, ставьте на свой комп и ...

Comment: С ядром особо больших проблем не будет. Разве что /dev может захотеть. Но если его перемонтировать в другую точку то вполне можно жить. Но вот библиотеку libc вам придется сделать свою, но вы про нее и не спрашивали (хотя должны были, потому что свою вы будете делать не один год, а без нее вы каждую запускаемую программу будете писать сами и прямыми обращениями к ядру). Ну и не забывайте, что очень многие программы сами по себе ожидают видеть /dev и /proc там где они сейчас, так что многие из стандартных программ, вам так же надо будет сделать свои

Comment: @Mike даже не знаю, как задать вопрос. Довольно сложная тема, а я не очень разбираюсь.
Я думаю: можно ли как-то создать фиктивную рут-папку для приложений с сылками на другие папки в системе, чтобы приложения обращались к нужным папкам, но мне вообще не кажется, что удастся полностью адаптировать современные линуксовские приложения под такую систему.
Вообще вопрос не про приложения, а про возможности самого ядра. Насколько удобно и просто будет создать такую операционную систему на ядре линукс: надо ли будет менять код ядра или нет.
А приложения под такую систему можно отдельно написать.

Comment: см. chroot делаете на нем отдельный виртуальный корень и тренируетесь. Все папки какие надо монтируете в нужные точки (см. mount --bind для монтирования копий). Или вообще в docker контейнере все это разворачиваете. Ядру в общем то фиолетово где что лежит. куда mount смонтировал с тем и работает. Только не забыть при загрузке параметрами ядра указать какой процесс первым стартовать, по умолчанию оно /sbin/init запускает